# If helper methods should not interact directly with the database in rails, Why do we put @current_user as helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read in [this blog](http://johnotander.com/rails/2014/03/07/decorators-on-rails/) that helper methods should not interact with the database directly or manipulate data for views. These tasks should be handled by decorators.

If this is the case, why do we typically put the @current_user methods in helper modules? (In Rails)

Comment: How exactly does calling `@current_user` manipulate the data?

Comment: It interacts with the database (at least when I use it). When called, it returns the current user or tries to find if such user exists in the database and then appropriately assigning. I'm asking if we are meant to handle such calls in decorators. I started reading up on decorators and presenters today and that part has me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will cite recap from [coderwall.com](https://coderwall.com/p/jx9tca/when-i-use-helpers-partials-presenters-and-decorators)

> Helpers
>
> Helpers are generic methods which can be use for different kind of objects. I create this kind of helpers `link_to_update`, `big_image`, `styled_form`, etc. Those methods create an html code with a css style or a standard text for example.
>
> Partials
>
> Partials are used to split a big view into smaller logic parts and for larger html code. I can have a partial `side_menu`, `comment_list`, `header`, etc.
>
> Presenters
>
> Presenters is for more complicated queries with two or more models. I have some partials like `@page_presenter.page_in_category(ruby_category)` or `@user_presenter.user_following(an_article)`.
>
> Decorators
>
> Decorators should act with only one model and shouldn't take parameters (if it's possible). I can do something like this `user.full_name`, `page.big_title` or `category.permalink`. I use the gem Draper.

So, essentially `decorators` are things which take data from *single model object* and manipulate it in some way (for example, squishing `first_name` + `last_name` into `full_name` and such things).

`current_user`, on the other hand, definitely doesn't belong to the decorators because it doesn't deal with manipulating any object's data – it actually `finds` the object you need (using session/cookies data for that).

I'd say its place is in `ApplicationController` (or one of its specific descendants which you can build, say, `AuthenticatedController` or such), because you often need to know `current_user` in a controller itself (not its view), and it takes unneeded efforts to make your view helper method available for controller.

Comment: Ok.. So if I understand correctly, the choice between helpers, partials and decorators are guided by what would need the data they provide. Decorators just give you prettier variables (like concatenated strings) to be used in the views. Helpers allow you hide some logic to better clean up the view (especially when the returned object could be needed in the view but not the controller).
But if its needed in the controller, then it should be in ApplicationController (or a specific descendant). This is what you mean, right?

Comment: Yes, choice is guided by that, and also from what object(s) they fetch the data they need. Decorators not necessarily are used *only* by the views. Key point: they decorate *single model object*. You can use their methods, for example, in controllers to set `flash` or such things. Helpers are mostly dealing with hiding HTML from plain site and wrapping it inside of Ruby function, yes. `current_user` is fetching specific data from the database – and that's exactly what controllers are for (though complex queries should be wrapped in model methods).

Comment: Oh ...Thanks. One follow-up question though. You said _Helpers are mostly dealing with hiding HTML from plain site and wrapping it inside of Ruby function_ . Does this mean we could write html inside helper methods? For example, If I need to display certain data sequel to an iteration, could I directly write such in my helper methods, thus abstracting it totally from the view?

Comment: It sounds like partial is better option. Really simple (like, one line of HTML) parts of markup could go to helpers. Well, almost all Rails built-in helpers are such lines of HTML.

Comment: @Cent By the way, if you consider my answer satisfactory, you should accept it (press V-shaped mark near it) :)

Comment: **laughs** sure, Just accepted it. Thanks for taking your time out to break down these concepts for me. I'm already seeing various applications of your suggestions on my current project code refractoring.